# Do I have to specify a depth texture in Metal or is one automatically allocated for me?

Tags: ios, metal

This could potentially be a swift vs objective-c thing but I have seen some example code where the depth texture is specefically assigned in `MTLRenderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture` and other times where this texture is never created like in the default metal project by Apple.

How does the Apple example get away with not allocating a depth texture? Are disadvantages to doing or not doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an `MTKView` and specify something other than `.invalid` as the `.depthStencilPixelFormat`, a depth texture will be created and managed for you. Otherwise, in order to get correct depth behavior, you must create a depth texture yourself and specify it on the render pass descriptor.

Comment: But, of course, there are cases where you don't need to "get correct depth behavior", in which case you don't need a depth attachment.